# How to install GCC 7.1.0 in RHEL6.4

Tags: c++, gcc, rhel6

I am using RHEL 6.4, I know installing through yum command,

but I want to download offline mode Linux RPM(version 7.1.0) GCC package and install(for c/c++ programs),

I searched on the internet but not able to find out the solution,

please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by "offline mode"?

Comment: I want to download complete GCC RPM and copy to my Linux server install in that system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access the package via `yum` then you can either *download and install* or you can *download an already installed* package as `rpm` file.
[Here is written how](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154), I quoted it anyways.

If you have that `rpm` file you can install it also via yum: `yum install packageName.rpm`, you may have to invoke `sudo`.

The package names for the C/C++ compiler are: `gcc.x86_64` (C: 64bit) and `gcc-c++.x86_64` (C++: 64bit) or `gcc.i686` (C: 32bit) and `gcc-c++.i686` (C++: 32bit).

If the downloaded version via yum, which is the latest available for your system, is not the version you want, you have to download the sources and [build it on your own, see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC).

> There are two ways to download a package without installing it.
>
> One is using the "downloadonly" plugin for yum, the other is using "yumdownloader" utility.
>
> ### Downloadonly plugin for yum
>
> Install the package including "downloadonly" plugin:
>
> ```
> (RHEL5)
> # yum install yum-downloadonly
>
> (RHEL6)
> # yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
> ```
>
> Run yum command with "--downloadonly" option as follows:
>
> ```
> # yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
> ```
>
> Confirm the RPM files are available in the specified download directory.
>
> Note:
>
> - Before using the plugin, check /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/downloadonly.conf to confirm that this plugin is "enabled=1"
> - This is applicable for "yum install/yum update" and not for "yum groupinstall". Use "yum groupinfo" to identify packages within a specific group.
> - If only the package name is specified, the latest available package is downloaded (such as sshd). Otherwise, you can specify the full package name and version (such as httpd-2.2.3-22.el5).
> - If you do not use the --downloaddir option, files are saved by default in /var/cache/yum/ in rhel-{arch}-channel/packages
> - If desired, you can download multiple packages on the same command.
>     You still need to re-download the repodata if the repodata expires before you re-use the cache. By default it takes two hours to expire.
>
> ### Yumdownloader
>
> If downloading a installed package, "yumdownloader" is useful.
>
> Install the yum-utils package:
>
> ```
> # yum install yum-utils
> ```
>
> Run the command followed by the desired package:
>
> ```
> # yumdownloader <package>
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> - The package is saved in the current working directly by default; use the --destdir option to specify an alternate location.
> - Be sure to add --resolve if you need to download dependencies.

Comment: Please specify the name of the package or how can I find that package particular name

Comment: I assume that you already installed the package via yum on your clients computer. Isn't that right? What does `yum info gcc-c++` outputs under Version?

Comment: I have a fresh Linux server, I didn't install any software, I have no internet access in my home so, i am copying GCC compiler from the internet and i will bring back to my home and i will install my Linux server.

Comment: I want complete download software and put into some external drive bring to my system..

Comment: Then the package names are: `gcc.x86_64` (C: 64bit) and `gcc-c++.x86_64` (C++: 64bit) and `gcc.i686` (C: 32bit) and `gcc-c++.i686` (C++: 32bit). With that follow the instructions above!

Comment: I am not able to install yum command because of lack of internet. So, I need complete offline package or installer...

Comment: Yeah sure, but on any computer you have to download it with internet access like you write: `i am copying GCC compiler from the internet and i will bring back to my home`. If you have no Linux system with internet try `https://www.rpmfind.net/`. But **caution**, you will find fedora packages. Most times they are compatible with RHEL but you want install a sensible part, so take backups. So I recomment install same Linux system to download it!

Comment: Is there any way to install GCC 4.8.5 rpm in RHEL 6.4,

Comment: @Lavakusa: In your title you wrote you want version 7.1.0, now you write 4.8.5!? What is the problem with my instructions? Please tell.

Comment: I followed your instructions It's working,  I want to install GCC 4.8.5 but when I installed GCC version is 4.4.7. Is there anyway.

Comment: my minimum requirement is 4.8.5 but I thought 7.1.0 is good for me, I follow your instructions I installed  GCC 4.4.7

Comment: downloaded rpm is :- gcc-c++-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: If that is the latest version via yum available, then you have to [build newer sources](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) on your own or use rpmfind as I said already.

Comment: Yes, I tried with that, i am not able to find the RedHat  GCC rpm, but i found Centos--- gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64,  Installed , Result is :---                **libgcc = 4.4.7-18.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest**

Comment: @Lavakusa: Then build it, as I said.